# how to make golang execute a string

Tags: go

I am not asking to make golang do some sort of "eval" in the current context, just need it to take a input string (say, received from network) and execute it as a separate golang program.

In theory, when you run `go run testme.go`, it will read the content of `testme.go` into a string and parse, compile and execute it. Wonder if it is possible to call a go function to execute a string directly. Note that I have a requirement not to write the string into a file.

**UPDATE1**

I really want to find out if there is a function (in some go package) that serves as an entry point of go, in another word, I can call this function with a string as parameter, it will behave like `go run testme.go`, where testme.go has the content of that string.

Comment: Where does the requirement to not write intermediate files comes from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK it cannot be done, and the go compiler has to write intermediate files, so even if you use `go run` and not `go build`, files are created for the sake of running the code, they are just cleaned up if necessary. So you can't run a go program without touching the disk, even if you manage to somehow make the compiler take the source not from a file.

For example, running `strace` on calling `go run` on a simple hello world program, shows among other things, the following lines:

```
mkdir("/tmp/go-build167589894", 0700) 
// ....
mkdir("/tmp/go-build167589894/command-line-arguments/_obj/exe/", 0777) 
// ... and at the end of things
unlink("/tmp/go-build167589894/command-line-arguments/_obj/exe/foo") 
// ^^^ my program was called foo.go
// ....
// and eventually:
rmdir("/tmp/go-build167589894")
```

So you can see that go run does a lot of disk writing behind the scenes, just cleans up afterwards.

I suppose you can mount some tmpfs and build in it if you wish, but otherwise I don't believe it's possible.

Comment: Thanks @Not_a_Golfer for the idea of using strace.  Sounds like the only possibility is to create ramdisk so go will write the intermediate files in thse ramdisk. Wonder if there is a package for it.

Comment: @codingFun on most recent linux distros, /tmp is a ramdisk (tmpfs).

Comment: @OneOfOne: that's far from universally true. Most do have a block of shared memory mapped to `/run/shm`, or `/dev/shm` though.

Comment: @JimB good to know, I'm personally using arch and tried 1 or 2 other that had it that way too.

Comment: Thanks guys for the points. I have clarified the question with update1.

Comment: ok. @Not_a_Golfer, I will accept your answer as the best then.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this question is (5 years) old but I wanted to say that actually, it is possible now, for anyone looking for an up-to-date answer.

The Golang compiler is itself written in Go so can theoretically be embedded in a Go program. This would be quite complicated though.

As a better alternative, there are projects like [yaegi](https://github.com/containous/yaegi) which are effectively a Go interpreter which can be embedded into Go programs.